# Excel::Writer::XLSX for Perl: How do I test a feature is supported by the module?

Tags: perl, version, excel-writer-xlsx

I have exercised a lot of features of this module, but sometimes have to install into an environment that has an older version of the module that doesn't have the features I have implemented.

So what's the best way to handle this?
- Version check?
- try{} catch{}?

Answer (score 2):

All perl objects extend from the `UNIVERSAL` module  which

> [is the base class from which all blessed references inherit](https://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html)

You can call `can` on the module to test to see if a particular method is implemented in the package.

```
perl -MExcel::Writer::XLSX -e 'if (Excel::Writer::XLSX->can("set_vba_name")) {print "It can";}';

perl -MExcel::Writer::XLSX -e '$xlsx = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new("/tmp/file");  if ($xlsx->can("add_worksheet")) {print "It can"}';
```

I'd avoid using version checking, it makes testing and development much harder, but can work in a pinch.

Ultimately, you want a consistent runtime environment, so you could create a makefile that installs all of the dependencies at the version you need.

Comment: Thanks very much! Oh, if only I could dictate the environment! But, I can't always. :( And my dev environment can get ahead of production. And I implement based on the latest features available in my dev. At least this way I can sense whether something is not possible and ignore it.